# Cannot get the call of my procedure to output the correct Revenue

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I am trying to create a procedure that outputs the total revenue of a specific orderNumber when inputed. However when I run my procedure below for the specific ordernumber of 10100 sql returns the total of all order revenue for every ordernumber. How can I alter my procedure to return the specific order revenue of a specific ordernumber when outputted?

```
use salesshort;
drop procedure if exists orderTotal;

DELIMITER //

create procedure orderTotal(in orderNumber int(11))
begin
    
    select orderNumber, sum(quantityOrdered * priceEach) as 'Orders_Revenue' 
    from orderdetails
    group by orderNumber;

end//
Delimiter ;

call orderTotal('10100')
```

Comment: Do you think that `orderNumber` in your SELECT are table column references? That is not true - this is an input variable. To refer the column you must use `orderdetails.orderNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE orderTotal(IN orderNumber INT)
    SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered * priceEach) AS Orders_Revenue
    FROM orderdetails
    WHERE orderdetails.orderNumber = orderNumber;
```